# WordPress - Code Snippet plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, posts

I am working on a new Wordpress blog and it's very important to have code snippets in it.

So to highlight the code snippet I downloaded a Code Snippet plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/codesnippet-20/

Now, everything is screwed up. Below is the error when I access the site.

Warning: require_once(geshi.php): failed to open stream:

`No such file or directory in /home1/jamburster/public_html/wp-content/plugins/codesnippet-20/codesnippet.php on line 126`

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'geshi.php' 
(include_path='.:/opt/php56/lib/php:/home1/jamburster/public_html//wp-content/plugins/codesnippet/lib:/home1/jamburster/public_html//wp-content/plugins/codesnippet/lib/PEAR') 
in /home1/jamburster/public_html/wp-content/plugins/codesnippet-20/codesnippet.php on line 126
```

Here is what I did.
1. Downloaded the archive from https://wordpress.org/plugins/codesnippet-20/
2. Uploaded the plugin WordPress -> Plugins -> Add Plugin. Browsed the downloaded one and clicked on upload.
3. Activated the plugin.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you, using crayon syntax highlighter instead of current plugin

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks to me like the plugin is having trouble finding a file called geshi.php. I just downloaded the plugin and activated it in my WordPress admin dashboard and I got the same error. So this isn't specific to you. One thing to note is that this plugin is not currently being maintained.

> *"This plugin hasn’t been updated in over 2 years. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used
>   with more recent versions of WordPress."*

However, I believe I have a fix for you. Go into your plugin and open the codesnippet.php file. Go to line 126 and replace that line with this:

```
require_once('/lib/geshi.php');
```

It looks like the directory structure of the plugin got changed without the necessary changes being made in the code base. I just tried this change on my machine and I am now able to activate the plugin without WordPress crashing. I haven't tried to use it, though.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I added this plugin by uploading the downloaded zipped folder. 
Just by changing this in my local how would it reflect in the wordpress site?When I try to access the site, it gives me the error that I mentioned. So, I cannot do anything on the site presently.

Comment: so take the downloaded zip file, go into the codesnippet.php file, make the change i told you to, save the change, then upload folder with the changes instead of uploading the plugin that is defective. However, you might be better off with @esmail answer.